# OutOfMemoryException in c# while writing to FileStream

Tags: c#, buffer, filestream, out-of-memory

OutOfMemoryExcetpion in c# ... I am trying to create a new index that is mainly based on BPlus trees. The index is supposed to be used on huge amounts of data (more than 50 000 000 items). In order to make the index fast I am keeping the internal tree nodes (each node has ~ 4KB of information, 256 references to child nodes) in RAM (they are frequently accessed). The leaves (variable size) are written to the disk, into files of maximum 200MB.
In order to write or read the data from a file I am using the following:

```
FileStream _FS = new FileStream(FullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
...
byte[] Data = new byte[size];
_FS.Read(Data, 0, size);
...
_FS.Write(Data, 0, _BlockSize);
```

The problem is that at a higher number of inserted items (19 000 000) I get the OutOfMemoryException. I understand that the internal structure of the tree (internal nodes) may occupy a huge amount of memory, however, I believe that this is not the reason why the memory is full.

When I am using the following constructor:

```
_FS = new FileStream(FullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
FileShare.None, 1024, FileOptions.WriteThrough | Settings.FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING);
```

the OutOfMemoryException is not raised (at least not at 20 000 000 items), however, the speed at which items are inserted is smaller.
I believe that when using the first FileStream constructor .net uses some internal buffer (in RAM), which fills the memory and results in raising the OutOfMemoryException.

The question is, how to use the FileStream (or something else) in order to be able to insert items (write to disk) at a high speed, withou raising the OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: The exception is not related to the stream itself, you need to show other parts of your code and explain more how you store/allocate the tree in memory.

Comment: what is the value of `size` here?

Comment: also; you mention "items" - is it an item per file? or...? (I'm trying to see how often `Data` is allocated)

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you put a _FS.Flush() in the loop for your first example, say every 10000 records?